# Android Nearby subscribe failed: 2807 Missing microphone permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, microphone, google-nearby

I'm trying to integrate Android Nearby (https://developers.google.com/nearby/) into my app, however when I try to use `nearby.subscribe` it fails with a "Missing microphone permission" error.

Since I could not find such a permission to add to `AndroidManifest.xml`, I searched for a bit and tried to add `RECORD_AUDIO`, but unfortunately it does not fix the problem.

Permissions asked (also at runtime):

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Code:

```
val nearby = Nearby.getMessagesClient(this, MessagesOptions.Builder().setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE).build())
nearby.publish(Message("Hello".toByteArray()))
nearby.subscribe(object : MessageListener() {
   override fun onDistanceChanged(p0: Message?, p1: Distance?) {
      super.onDistanceChanged(p0, p1)
      toast("onDistanceChanged")
   }
   override fun onLost(p0: Message?) {
      super.onLost(p0)
      toast("onLost")
   }
   override fun onBleSignalChanged(p0: Message?, p1: BleSignal?) {
      super.onBleSignalChanged(p0, p1)
      toast("onBleSignalChanged")
   }

   override fun onFound(p0: Message?) {
      super.onFound(p0)
      toast("onFound")
   }
}).addOnFailureListener { toast("onFailure " + it.message) }
  .addOnSuccessListener { toast("onSuccess") }
```

Error:

```
2807: Missing microphone permission
```

How can I make the Nearby API work?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution @matan-tsuberi ?

Comment: Not really, no.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Nearby `MessagesClient`, you're specifying you'll use **BLE permissions only**. By default, the nearby connections api uses [Strategy.DEFAULT](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/Strategy#DEFAULT)  which includes microphone access. Your subscription/publication will therefore fail from not having microphone permission.

To make Nearby API work, pass [Subscribe Options](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/SubscribeOptions) and [Publish Options](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/PublishOptions) that use the requested [NearbyPermissions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/NearbyPermissions) when subscribing or publishing respectively e.g. Strategy.BLE_ONLY for only NearbyPermissions.BLE.

Refer to the api explanation/documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/NearbyPermissions). [This](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/NearbyMessagesStatusCodes#MISSING_PERMISSIONS) is your error code and description.